# Have lost all Google information to allow me to sign into my Google accounts

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

Have been trying to login to my accounts and not able to as I have forgotten all emails, passwords, username and how I sign up as per name.  Have no idea estimated (date) when I signed up but has been years.  No memory of password or hint of one.
Thinking of going into Hardware and Features and just deleting Google completely but don't know if that is the correct way and then open another account.

Answer (score 0):

If you've legitimately forgotten everything, there is no hope. If you can remember your original email address, you can consult a backup account or phone number if you have set these up. Otherwise, you have no chance of getting back in.